# Geom_rect não reconhece o alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um gráfico feito com `geom_rect`, o problema é que estou usando o argumento `alpha` e ele não está aplicando a transparência no gráfico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
dados %>%
    mutate(median_x = inicio + floor((fim - inicio) / 2)) %>%
    filter(data > "1996-01-01") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data)) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = inicio, xmax = fim, ymin = 0 , ymax = Inf),
              fill = "grey", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = ipca_12, color = "IPCA 12 meses (1980 - atualidade;1979 = INPC, Anteriores = IGPC - MTB)")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = selic, color = "Selic Over Efetiva % aa (1974 - atualidade; Anteriores = ORTN)")) +
    geom_text(aes(x = median_x , y= 10, label = presidente), angle = 90, size = 3.5, check_overlap = TRUE) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::comma) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Em log", color = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dashed"),
          text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Meu `dput`:

```
structure(list(data = structure(c(9527, 9556, 9587, 9617, 9648, 
9678, 9709, 9740, 9770, 9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 
10013, 10043, 10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 
10286, 10317, 10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 
10561, 10592, 10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 
10835, 10865, 10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017), class = "Date"), 
    ipca_12 = c(21.9876487892542, 20.5461403840636, 19.1692099510913, 
    17.4861929604506, 16.2568733196557, 14.8371674614145, 14.2117546274331, 
    13.2617806311261, 12.022054997554, 10.7524643476359, 9.5638055632826, 
    9.39082146134727, 8.81696087167574, 8.99046075946317, 8.58145053737551, 
    7.71254147854057, 7.02064354434697, 6.07861631900357, 5.59279230957765, 
    5.49790113326349, 5.42427348541379, 5.26664149754683, 5.22473181644896, 
    4.73594328162261, 4.69425733404785, 4.51718019001452, 3.85410529586692, 
    3.94719233377776, 3.4095700937383, 3.05874936103157, 2.55366047138457, 
    2.26668240890218, 2.05241519044592, 1.75696545095076, 1.65564416702073, 
    1.64555026927797, 2.24251298736351, 3.01692309171269, 3.34578796989853, 
    3.14012471025693, 3.3154278616341, 4.56704648110322, 5.69164935309818, 
    6.25305017648108, 7.49596228112497, 8.64755098397645, 8.93993450601047, 
    8.85338838127878, 7.86234318275554, 6.92348203536857), selic = c(36.11, 
    30.16, 29.42, 25.64, 29.65, 23.28, 25.01, 25.4, 23.48, 25.27, 
    23.94, 21.73, 26.14, 24.11, 21.84, 21.91, 21.08, 19.04, 20.78, 
    19.81, 19.93, 45.9, 39.87, 37.19, 34.32, 28.32, 25.16, 22.6, 
    21.02, 20.33, 19.23, 34.29, 41.6, 38.73, 31.24, 31.19, 38.97, 
    43.25, 36.12, 27.11, 22.01, 20.74, 19.51, 19.38, 18.91, 18.95, 
    18.99, 18.94, 18.87, 18.85), presidente = c("P. Arida", "P. Arida", 
    "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", 
    "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", 
    "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", "P. Arida", 
    "P. Arida", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", 
    "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", 
    "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", 
    "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", "G. Franco", 
    "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", 
    "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", 
    "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga", "A. Fraga"), inicio = structure(c(9435, 
    9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 
    9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9435, 9100, 9100, 9100, 
    9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 
    9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 9100, 10651, 10651, 10651, 
    10651, 10651, 10651, 10651, 10651, 10651, 10651, 10651, 10651, 
    10651), class = "Date"), fim = structure(c(10043, 10043, 
    10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 
    10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10043, 10623, 10623, 
    10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 
    10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 10623, 12022, 
    12022, 12022, 12022, 12022, 12022, 12022, 12022, 12022, 12022, 
    12022, 12022, 12022), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema foi descrito em postagem do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521438/geom-rect-and-alpha-does-this-work-with-hard-coded-values). Resumidamente, a questão é que a função geom_rect() desenha um retângulo para cada linha do seu dataframe. Desse modo, os retângulos se sobrepõem e anulam o efeito da transparência. Há três opções para solucionar o problema:

**Opção 1:**

Uma opção é usar a função `annotate()` ao invés de `geom_rect()`. Como você quer desenhar vários retângulos, um para cada período relativo à presidência do Banco Central, então você pode usar uma função `annotate()` para cada período, especificando as dimensões de cada retângulo no eixo X, como no código abaixo:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
    mutate(median_x = inicio + floor((fim - inicio) / 2)) %>%
    filter(data > "1996-01-01") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data)) +
    annotate("rect", xmin=as.Date("1994-12-01"), xmax=as.Date("1999-02-01"), ymin=0, ymax=Inf,  fill="gray", alpha=0.2) +
    annotate("rect", xmin=as.Date("1999-03-01"), xmax=as.Date("2002-12-01"), ymin=0, ymax=Inf,  fill="gray", alpha=0.2) +    
geom_line(aes(y = ipca_12, color = "IPCA 12 meses (1980 - atualidade;1979 = INPC, Anteriores = IGPC - MTB)")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = selic, color = "Selic Over Efetiva % aa (1974 - atualidade; Anteriores = ORTN)")) +
    geom_text(aes(x = median_x , y= 10, label = presidente), angle = 90, size = 3.5, check_overlap = TRUE) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::comma) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Em log", color = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dashed"),
          text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Na amostra que você forneceu dos seus dados, há três presidentes do BC. Mas na sua imagem tem apenas dois retângulos relativos a esses três presidentes, pois você juntou os períodos do Gustavo Franco e do Pérsio Arida. Acima, fiz os dois retângulos relativos a esses dois períodos. Você precisaria adicionar ao gráfico novas linhas da função `annotate()`, uma para cada retângulo que você quer desenhar, quando utilizar essa solução nos seus dados completos. Talvez haja algum modo de automatizar isso, mas não descobri ainda e desse jeito que fiz funcionou.

**Opção 2:**

Uma segunda opção, que tenta automatizar a definição dos retângulos, é criar um novo dataframe com apenas uma linha para cada período relativo aos retângulos que você quer desenhar. Em seguida, você especifica que quer utilizar esse dataframe reduzido dentro da função `geom_rect()`. No código abaixo, criei um dataframe (`dados2`) com uma única linha para cada presidente do BC. O resultado não ficou igual ao desejado porque você juntou algumas presidências dentro do mesmo retângulo. Então precisaria fazer algumas recodificações para a criação do dataframe reduzido que você vai utilizar. Mas a ideia é simples: criar um dataframe com uma única linha para cada retângulo e utilizar esse dataframe dentro da função `geom_rect()`:

```
dados2<- dados[!duplicated(dados$presidente),]
dados %>%
    mutate(median_x = inicio + floor((fim - inicio) / 2)) %>%
    filter(data > "1996-01-01") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data)) +
    geom_rect(data = dados2, aes(xmin=inicio, xmax=fim, ymin=0, ymax=Inf,  fill="gray", alpha=0.2)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = ipca_12, color = "IPCA 12 meses (1980 - atualidade;1979 = INPC, Anteriores = IGPC - MTB)")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = selic, color = "Selic Over Efetiva % aa (1974 - atualidade; Anteriores = ORTN)")) +
    geom_text(aes(x = median_x , y= 10, label = presidente), angle = 90, size = 3.5, check_overlap = TRUE) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scales::comma) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Em log", color = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dashed"),
          text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

**Opção 3:**

Uma terceira alternativa, é especificar um valor muito baixo do alpha como por exemplo `alpha=0.001`, no código original e ver se o nível desejado de transparência é atingido.

Comment: Obrigado pela solução! Tentei utilizar o `annotate`, mas só consegui gerar apenas um retângulo, existe alguma forma de gerar todos os retângulos igual na foto que coloquei?

Comment: Acabei de ver que tem sim, já atualizei minha resposta procurando aprimorar o código da primeira opção para sua necessidade, e tentei explicar melhor também a opção 2.